# why am i getting some weird symbols as my output

Tags: c++

my code is

```
 #include<iostream>

 using namespace std;

 int main()
{
int size;

cout << "enter number of letters in your name\t:";

cin >> size;

char *array = new char[size];

cin.getline( array, size);

for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++)

    cout <<'\n'<< array[i];

delete[] array;

cin.get();
}
```

and my output is some weird thing

```
enter number of letters in your name    :5


/
 ≥

└
ramsay
```

and after this execution stops, for loop is newer executed.

I know i am using old styled string but we have to use this as recommended by our high school

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++)` is wrong. It should be `for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)` because `array[size]` is out of bounds. Valid indices are from 0 to size-1

Comment: What did you mean to do by `cin.getline(array, size)`?

Comment: @drescherjm still you get weird symbols

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21567292/3410396 . Although it talks about C++ strings, underlying cause and solution is exactly the same.

Comment: if your name is of `size` letters, you should allocate at least `size+1` chars in `array`

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot Hm, I wonder if I should close the dupe I closed with to be a dupe of that one.

Comment: @Barry even after adding  that `cin.ignore()` i get same symbols

Comment: @ramsay How you did that? Where did you put it? What is your code?